# Скорость работы ассемблерной вставки

Tags: ассемблер, производительность, x86

Есть два блока кода с ассемблерной вставкой в visual studio. В одном mov'ы стоят до цикла loop, в другом - внутри цикла. Цикл прогоняется, скажем, 1.000.000.000 раз.
Идет замер времени с помощью chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().

Уточнение: В рабочем коде операций add не одна, а 25, чтобы погрешность при переходе на след. цикл была не так значительна. Перед этим я прогоняю те же вставки, но без операций add, чтобы измерить погрешность. Это учитывается при сравнении.

Вопрос: почему при использовании mov`ов в цикле время работы уменьшается (возрастает производительность) даже если в eax, ebx заносятся 0? Разница в 1.5-2 раза.

Первый вариант (скорость ниже):

```
auto numberOfOperations = 1000000000;
t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
_asm {
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, b
    mov ecx, numberOfOperations
    lp_test_time :
        add eax, ebx   // 25 операций в моем коде
        add eax, ebx
        ...
        add eax, ebx
    loop lp_test_time
}
t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
```

Второй вариант (скорость выше):

```
auto numberOfOperations = 1000000000;
t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
_asm {
    mov ecx, numberOfOperations
    lp_test_time :
        mov eax, a
        mov ebx, b
        add eax, ebx   // 25 операций в моем коде
        add eax, ebx
        ...
        add eax, ebx
    loop lp_test_time
}
t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
```

Comment: Подозрение - что-то с флагами связанное. Зависит только от местоположения `mov eax,a`, но не `ebx`...

Comment: @Harry, зависит от того, в какой регистр помещаем результат сложения. Вряд ли это как-то связано с флагами. Скорее, какие-то микроархитектурные детали.

Comment: @Harry, может, вам будет интересно. Я получил [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884433/8086115) на английском SO.

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо!

Comment: @Harry, всегда пожалуйста ;)